# what type is DWORD_PTR, LONG_PTR, UNIT_PTR

Tags: windows, types

I'm asking if its an integer, string, character or boolean.

I'm trying to use them like normal variable types. It would be best if someone answered them separately and consecutively, I know it would be better to ask Microsoft itself, but they say,

> "The following data types are always the size of a pointer, that is, 32 bits wide in 32-bit applications, and 64 bits wide in 64-bitapplications. The size is determined at compile time. When a 32-bit application runs on 64-bit
> Windows, these data types are still 4 bytes wide."

And I have no idea whatever that means.

Answer (score 2):

> "The following data types are always the size of a pointer,

Pointers are generally 4-bytes on 32-bit applications and 8-bytes on 64-bit applications

> that is, 32 bits wide in 32-bit applications, and 64 bits wide in
> 64-bitapplications.

What I just said.

> 32-bitapplication runs on 64-bit Windows, these data types are still 4
> bytes wideThe size is determined at compile time. When a

The pointer size on a 32-bit application running on 64-bit Windows is still 4 bytes.

Basically breaks down like this:

For 32-bit apps (running on 32-bit or 64-bit OS):

```
DWORD_PTR => unsigned long
LONG_PTR => long
UINT_PTR => unsigned int
// sizeof(int) and sizeof(long) are both 4 on 32-bit windows
```

On 64-bit apps that only run on 64-bit windows

```
DWORD_PTR => unsigned __int64
LONG_PTR => __int64
UINT_PTR => unsigned __int64
```

Back in the day, before 64-bit Windows, Microsoft recognized a habit of developers was to smuggle pointers (often to C++ class instances) to data across different APIs and libraries by casting to integer.

Case in point.  Seeing this smack in the middle of some code that was trying to send some data between different windows in the same application:

```
 SendMessage(hWnd, WM_MY_CUSTOM_MESSAGE, (WPARAM)ptrToSomeData, (LPARAM)ptrToSomeObject);
```

When 64-bit Windows came along, a lot of these APIs and programming techniques were inherently broken because assumptions made that "DWORD" or "unsigned int" was always big enough for a pointer case. For other app compat and code reasons, they wouldn't just blindly make all these types 8-bytes wide on 64-bit builds.  So the *_PTR types were invented for developers that wanted to build coding patterns that enabled another developer to freely pass an absolute integer or a pointer.

> and I have no idea whatever that means

I hope you do now.